# Употребление дефиса: варикозно-расширенный, варикозно-измененный, импульсивно-волновой, ладыжечно-плечевой, венно-специфичный

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно-дефис

При ***варикозно (-) расширенных*** венах
Удаление ***варикозно (-) измененных*** притоков
***Импульсивно (-) волновой*** допплер
С ***варикозно (-) измененными*** подкожными венами
Снижение ***ладыжечно (-) плечевого*** индекса
Купирование ***вено (-) специфичных*** симптомов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом согласен с Людмилой, только пробелы вокруг дефисов не нужны.

Добавлю, не ставя под сомнение её рекомендации.

"Варикозно-измененный" - тут нет единого мнения. Это термин. Аналогично "варикрозно-расширенный". На мой вкус тут скорее именно варикозные и измененные (расширенные). О наречии "варикозно" не слышал, в словарях его нет. Тем не менее, согласен с раздельным написанием, по крайней мере вне специальной литературы.

"Импульсивно-волновой допплер" - что дефис не сомневаюсь, но что такое допплер (да еще с двойным П)? Если сам прибор, то могу понять. Но если, как в литературе - *метод исследования*? Тогда прилагательное становится несколько странным, тавтологичным. Увы, не силен. *Но уж если самого Доплера прекрасно пишут с одним П, то уж прибор его имени как-нибудь без двух обойдется, не?*

"Лодыжечно-плечевой индекс" - здесь именно О, потому, что имеется в виду "лодыжка" - научное название щиколотки, а не "ладыжка" - замок стрелкового механизма. Хотя, признаться, между этими понятиями есть много общего, фонетическое сходство порождено общей этимологией.

Comment: Кристиан Допплер, поэтому и две буквы "п". Хотя в просторах интернета есть варианты с одной "п". Например википедия пишет: доплерография (допплерография)

Comment: В клинических рекомендация по лечению хронических заболеваний термины "варикозно-измененный" и "варикозно-расширенный" написаны через "-"

Comment: @АннаЛебедева Вообще-то Википедия не знает варианта с одной П.  ======== https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80,_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD  ==============  Сколько помню, вариантов с ПП до вас не видел.

Comment: *В клинических рекомендация по лечению хронических заболеваний термины "варикозно-измененный" и "варикозно-расширенный" написаны через "-".*  - да, я же сказал, мне тоже хосется так написать. Но есть словари обшей лексики...

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Анна,Вы пишете, "В клинических рекомендациях", а в каких и кто их давал?. Я вот в свои посмотрела, лежала в клинике при медуниверситете, люди там грамотные - доценты в основном, написано без дефиса. Вот Википедия и ещё несколько сайтов:. Клиническая классификация. (С)
•C2: Варикозно расширенные веныhttps://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%4. http://varicose.com.ua/oslogneniya_varikoznoiy_bolezni.html
 http://farmamir.ru/2013/09/mazi-dlya-lecheniya-varikoznogo-rasshirennyx-ven/
  http://mkb-10.com/index.php?pid=8413nwvaricose_legs-post001.html

Comment: @Людмила, из всех ваших ссылок работает только одна, но и она - на украинский сайт, не авторитетно.  Попробуйте дать ссылки в тексте основного ответа. Там вам проще будет разобраться в приинах ошибки, скорее всего просто строки очень длинные.

Comment: http://webmed.irkutsk.ru/doc/pdf/ven2009.pdf

Comment: И в тексте доППлер и доППлерография

Answer (score 5):

При варикозно расширенных венах.Расширенных как? варикозно - наречие.

Удаление варикозно  измененных притоков

Импульсивно-волновой допплер. Импульсивный и волновой.

С варикозно измененными подкожными венами.

Снижение л**о**дыжечно-плечевого индекса.

Купирование вено-специфичных симптомов

Comment: Людмила, а зачеи пробелы вокруг дефисов?

Comment: Так скопировала у автора, перепечатывать лень. Нет, конечно, никаких пробелов, это дефисы.

Answer (score 3):

При **варикозно-расширенных** венах, удаление **варикозно-измененных** притоков, **импульсивно-волновой** допплер,  с **варикозно-измененными** подкожными венами, снижение **лодыжечно-плечевого** индекса, купирование **веноспецифичных** симптомов.

**Это термины,** а термины обычно имеют **слитное или дефисное** написание (раздельное написание наречие+прилагательное для них нехарактерно). **Через дефис** обычно пишутся термины, составленные **из основ прилагательных**, **слитное** написание используется в том случае, если первой основой является основа **существительного**.

**Примечание.** Фактически большинство сложных прилагательных из области терминологии должны бы по правилам орфографии писаться слитно (способ образования слова - **чистое сложение наречия и опорного прилагательного)**, но слитное написание неудобно для прочтения таких слов, поэтому оно заменяется дефисным.

**Справочная информация**

1) **Эффе́кт До́плера** — изменение частоты  излучения, воспринимаемое наблюдателем (приёмником), вследствие движения источника излучения и/или движения наблюдателя (приёмника). На эффекте Допплера основана работа медицинских приборов, связанная **с измерением скорости частиц по изменению их частоты.**

2) Многие термины являются парными:  импульсно-волновой допплер (прибор) и постоянно-волнового допплер; лодыжечно-плечевой индекс и пальце-плечевой индекс.

Comment: *Многие термины являются парными:* а что тут парного? И к чему это вообще замечание?

Comment: В парных терминах опорное прилагательное одно и то же, а различаются они по первой основе, получается не одно название, а системная терминология с одинаковым написанием. Например: лодыжечно-плечевой  и пальце-плечевой индекс. Хотя здесь первые основы разные (основа прилагательного и основа существительного), но написание одинаковое (термины одного порядка, одной системы). Скорее всего, во втором случае основа считается усеченной (пальцево-плечевой индекс).

Comment: Это потом всё. Для начала: что такое вообще "парный термин"? По какому принципу "парные"? Я знаю парные видовые глаголы. Парные глаголы движения. Ну еще там "парные" (хотя это уже отсебятина) причастия-прилагательные с одинаковым или близким написанием. Все остальное нуждается в объяснении используемой Вами терминологии. "Сине-зеленый" и "красно-зеленый" - это парные термины? А если еще "желто-зеленый" добавить, то они тройными станут?

Comment: Действительно, вы правы, парные термины - это не очень понятное название, можно условно назвать их классификационнными терминами (или как-то еще). Если какое-либо устройство представлено  модельным рядом, то такой же ряд составляют и видовые названия (два или большее количество). С точки зрения орфографии важно то, что они имеют одну форму написания, то есть  задача выбора формы  решается для них одинаково (здесь не требуется индивидуальный анализ).