# "Варикозно-измененные вены" пишется через дефис?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно-дефис

*Варикозно-измененные вены* пишется через дефис?

Comment: повтор вопроса  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424068/Употребление-дефиса/424072#424072

Answer (score 0):

1) **Если это термин** в научной литературе, то написание через дефис, например: **удаление варикозно-измененных притоков, жалобы на наличие варикозно-измененных вен.** В то же время и в научной литературе встречается раздельное написание.

https://medi.ru/docplus/f420607.htm.pdf

2) **Если это словосочетание** (в популярных статьях по этой теме), то написание обычно раздельное.

Comment: А по правилам? Измененные (как?) варикозно, следовательно...

Comment: Вопрос (как?) Вам не поможет, термины  образуются путем сложения наречия и прилагательного/причастия и по обычным правилам пишутся слитно. Однако в специальной литературе допускается дефисное написание терминов, ввиду сложности их прочтения при слитном написании. Поэтому может различаться дефисное написание в спец. литературе и раздельное написание в обычной.

Comment: Значит, раздельно написанное *варикозно измененные вены* — не термин?

Comment: Нет, не термин,  но может быть терминологическим словосочетанием.

Comment: А не кажется ли Вам, что терминологическое словосочетание — это тот же термин, только многословный?

Comment: Не кажется.  Я думаю, что в спец. литературе желательно использовать в качестве терминов слова, а не словосочетания. (Но это мое личное мнение). Пример на эту тему: личностно-ориентированный подход в обучении.  Дефисное написание вызывало много вопросов, но тем не менее утвердилось именно оно.

Comment: Я спросил, меняется ли статус (становится ли темин просто набором слов)  при раздельном написании, которое тоже встречается.  А ответ был фактически таков: если написано через дефис, то это термин, а если раздельно, то многословный термин. И что такой ответ дает уму и сердцу?

Comment: https://refdb.ru/look/2544461.html: На данный момент принято разграничивать однословные и многословные термины. Так, например, Б Л. Головин и Р.Ю. Кобрин (1987) подразделяют языковые средства выражения специальных понятий на термины-слова (непроизводные, производные, сложные, аббревиатуры) и термины - словосочетания или терминологические словосочетания.

Comment: Это было очевидно: термины разные бывают. В нашем случае мы обсуждали термины, полученные сложением наречия и прилагательного/причастия.